# Configuring Typescript Compiler to "see" typings and modules?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webstorm

I have a project in typescript that has the following layout:

```
<work folder>/Scripts/  (project root)
               +-- App
                     +--- subfolder1
                     +--- subfolder2
               +-- typings
```

I open my project (previously made by someone else in Visual Studio) and in Webstorm I am getting errors during TypeScript compilation.

1. Typings are not picked up: Error:(212, 23) TS2304: Cannot find name 'angular'.

Why the typings are not seen by compiler?

2. In some files in App/subfolder2 I can see references like

   *import MessageReceiver = require("App/subfolder1/SourceCode");*

that is, defined relative to top-level folder and "parallel" to subfolder2. Apparently it worked in Visual Studio, but here it generates errors: Error:(2, 34) TS2307: Cannot find module 'App/subfolder1/SourceCode'.

If I change path to a relative one (../subfolder1/SourceCode), error goes away, but I do not want to alter current code in any way  and therefore want to tell the Webstorm's compiler where to start looking for required modules that are defined relative to top-level folder. How I can do this?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://ivanz.com/2016/06/07/how-does-typescript-discover-type-declarations-definitions-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to make sure that TypeScript is configured to use `classic` module discovery mode instead of `node` one in your `tsconfig.json` and if you don't have one - maybe create one.

That should work assuming:

a) WebStorm has built their parsing/semantic engine on top of the TypeScript language service

... or ...

b) WebStorm respects the `tsconfig.json`

The difference between the `classic` and `node` module resolution is described here and it mostly boils down to TypeScript looking in `node_modules` when in `node` mode for module paths that don't start with `./` (relative to the current file): http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Have also a look at my blog post about typings and discovery: http://ivanz.com/2016/06/07/how-does-typescript-discover-type-declarations-definitions-javascript/